# best practice of Python 3 project structure

Tags: python, python-3.x

Read some online post about the best practice of python project structure but I am still not clear of it.
Why do we need a `main.py`?
Why do we need `__init__.py` and what should be in that file?
Why do we need command line arguments parsing?
...
What's the best place/resource that I can have a clear view of the right structure with good example that can help to understand this?

Thanks

Comment: You don't "need" main.py (the entry script could be called anything) or command line parsing (what if you had nothing to parse?)... Or an init if you don't have separate modules.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going through these links.

- Why __init__.py:  [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448271/7387951)
- Project Structure:  https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/

For project structures, you can also check popular GitHub repositories